# Validating params from two forms both using the same model in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I've recently implemented a phone/sim checker. The first form input requires the user to input their phone number. If the phone number exists in the database, render the phone number found message, otherwise replace the phone number form with the sim number form. Again if the sim number exists in the database, render the sim number found message, otherwise render the sim number not found message.

The problem im currently having is validating each form input for their min and max length. When I am outputting the errors for just the phone number form, I am getting: Sim number is too short (minimum is 12 characters) and Sim number is too long (maximum is 12 characters). And Phone number is too short (minimum is 11 characters) and Phone number is too long (maximum is 12 characters) when filling out the latter sim number form.

How do I get each form to just validate against its params, not the other form aswell?

Code Below:
app/models/phone.rb

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :phone_number, length: {minimum: 11, maximum: 11}, allow_blank: false
  validates :sim_number, length: {minimum: 12, maximum: 12}, allow_blank: false
end
```

app/controller/phones_controller.rb

```
class PhonesController < ApplicationController
  def checkphone
    @phone = Phone.new(phone_params)
      if @phone.invalid?
        render 'error'
      else
        @phone = Phone.where(phone_number: params[:phone][:phone_number])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @phone.exists?
            format.js {render 'phone-found'}
          else
            format.js {render 'phone-not-found'}
          end
        end
      end
  end

  def checksim
    @sim = Phone.new(sim_params)
      if @sim.invalid?
        render 'sim-error'
      else
        @sim = Phone.where('sim_number = ?', params[:sim][:sim_number])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @sim.exists?
            format.js {render 'sim-found'}
          else @sim.blank?
            format.js {render 'sim-not-found'}
          end
        end
      end
  end

  private

  def phone_params
    params.require(:phone).permit(
      :phone_number
    )
  end

  def sim_params
    params.require(:sim).permit(
      :sim_number
    )
  end
end
```

app/views/phones/index.html.erb

```
<div id="phone-number-found"></div>
<div id="phone-number-not-found"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<%= form_for :phone, :url => url_for(:action => 'checkphone', :controller => 'phones'), remote: true, html: { id: 'phone-number-form'}  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Phone Number:" %>
  <%= f.number_field :phone_number, minlength: 11, maxlength: 11, required: true %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check") %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/phones/phone-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('Phone Number Found!');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#error').html('');
$('#phone-number-form').hide();
```

app/views/phones/phone-not-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').append("<%= j render(partial: 'sim') %>")
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('Phone Number Not Found!');
$('#error').html('');
$('#phone-number-form').hide();
```

app/views/phones/error.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#error').html('<%= j render('errors') %>');
```

app/views/phones/_errors.html.erb

```
<% @phone.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <p>- <%= message %></p>
<% end %>
```

app/views/phones/_sim.html.erb

```
<div id="sim-number-found"></div>
<div id="sim-number-not-found"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<%= form_for :sim, :url => url_for(:action => 'checksim', :controller => 'phones'), remote: true, html: { id: 'sim-number-form'}  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Sim Number:" %>
  <%= f.number_field :sim_number, minlength: 12, maxlength: 12, required: true %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check") %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/phones/sim-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('Sim Found')
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-error').html('');
```

app/views/phones/sim-not-found.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('Sim Number Not Found!');
$('#error').html('');
```

app/views/phones/sim-error.js.erb

```
$('#phone-number-found').html('');
$('#phone-number-not-found').html('');
$('#error').html('<%= j render('sim_errors') %>');
```

app/views/phones/_sim-errors.html.erb

```
<% @sim.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <p>- <%= message %></p>
<% end %>
```

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `allow_nil: true` instead of `allow_blank: false`?

Comment: That worked thankyou :)

Comment: You can also add an `:if` to the sim validation to only check that once the phone number is set.

Comment: So :if phone_number? Sorry new to conditional validations. Both form inputs need to be required aswell. Are you ok to show me an example with my model?

Comment: Not sure of the business logic, but here's the syntax.  You would do something like `if: :phone_number_present?` and then create a method `def phone_number_present?; phone_number.present?; end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `allow_nil: true`. When the item isn't submitted with the form it will be ignored.

```
validates :phone_number, length: {minimum: 11, maximum: 11}, allow_nil: true
validates :sim_number, length: {minimum: 12, maximum: 12}, allow_nil: true
```